# how to use Libman json file in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, css, libman

Can I use libman.json to manage libraries file without using visual studio and core asp.net? If yes please tell me how?

Answer (score 5):

You can use LibMan without VS, but it does rely on the .NET platform.  There are is a NuGet package for a [.NET global tool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Cli/); obviously you need .NET Core installed to use it, but then you can integrate it into whatever scripts or platform you're using for development.

Answer (score 0):

When I code of Visual Studio , I uasually copy Libman.json file and paste in my file are running .